# Looking for a Basic Reverse Shell Example in C(++)

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp

I'm trying to find a basic reverse shell example in C or C++,

Basically I want to write a code to simulate the following netcat scenario:

```
Listener:
------------------
C:\nc -L -p 80

Client
--------------
C:\nc 127.0.0.1 80 -e cmd.exe
```

For whom doesn't speak netcat:

This means I want to redirect stdin and stdout from cmd.exe to network's stream in and out.
So a user from a remote box can run cmd.exe from the remote computer.

I'm looking for C / C++ example code to do this?

Comment: Here you have some pointers: 0x24804005, 0xEBF255FE, 0xE0443209...

Comment: You may be artificially limiting the pool of people who can help you to those who speak fluent netcat.

Comment: dmckee you right, I've just explained what's it actually about.

Answer (score 2):

`netcat` is basically something that either accepts (when acting as server) or opens (when acting as client) a socket.  Anything typed into `stdin` is written to the socket.  Anything read from the socket is written to `stdout`.  Any errors are written to `stderr`.

That's the basics.  It looks like you are using it on Windows and attaching the standard IO to a command shell.  I'm not sure why/what this does for you, so I'm going to ignore that for now.

Anyway, what you need to do is write an app that accepts/opens a socket, write to ... etc... (see paragraph 1).

There is a lot of stuff online that explains how to do this.  The ultimate answer to your question depends on why you want to do this (i.e. why not just use `netcat`), whether you want a nice POSIX compliant app that would build on any platform or something that is Windows only (and maybe uses Windows UI components), and other considerations.

I recommend you start by searching Google for something like [socket programming in c](http://www.google.com/search?q=socket+programming+in+c), [socket programming in c++](http://www.google.com/search?q=socket+programming+in+c%2B%2B&), or [Windows socket programming](http://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+socket+programming).